# Mongoengine: Querying the database from inside Document

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a class with a reference field on itself, because some users in my app can have sub users that are kinda like employees. I defined my Document this way:

```
class User(Document):
    __parent = ReferenceField('self', db_field='parent')
```

I tried to define a property inside my User model to retrieve the parent from inside the class but I haven't managed to make it work. I've read the documentation on [Default Document Queries](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/querying.html#default-document-queries) and have tried using queryset_manager decorator and then calling that function from my property but when I try that I get an error saying that 'QuerySetManager is not callable'.

Basically what I want to do is making the property return a User instance containing the parent of the child that is calling. I hope this can help visualize it.

```
@property
def get_parent(self):
    return self.objects(id=self.__parent).get()
```